# Get hostname when using TRAMP mode

Tags: tramp

Occasionally I use TRAMP mode to edit remote files.

I want to detect if the file open is remote, and if so, get the hostname of the server it's on.

I can't find any buffer-local variable that holds this information, though. `tramp-current-host` holds the hostname, but isn't buffer local.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding it out shortly after posting this question.

`(file-remote-p default-directory 'host)`

This works, returning nil if the file isn't remote, or the hostname if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, calling `file-remote-p` is the proper way. If you want to see the hostname in the modeline, I recommend you to install `tramp-theme` from GNU ELPA.